# Python best practices for large project

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Imagine a large project that contains a lot of modules and directories.
For example (structure taken from https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

```
sound/
   __init__.py
   formats/
      __init__.py
      wavread.py
      wavwrite.py
      aiffread.py
      aiffwrite.py
      auread.py
      auwrite.py
      ...
   effects/
      __init__.py
      echo.py
      surround.py
      reverse.py
      ...
   filters/
      __init__.py
      equalizer.py
      vocoder.py
      karaoke.py
      ...
conf/
   sound.conf
```

Also project has configure file. A lot of project's modules use configure file. 

In every module we can perform open('path_to_sound.conf', 'r'). But  it will happened every time we call 'import ' ... So it is inefficient approach.
 

I want to read sound.conf only once.
I want to share single configure structure between all modules.

What is best practices?

Comment: Module code is executed just *once* on import, when loading the module. After the module is loaded importing only involves binding names.

Comment: But if there are a lot of intra-package dependencies within a project? And the same module could be imported many times.

Comment: Importing is a two stage process: loading the file *if not yet loaded*, and binding names. Loading the file happens just the once, regardless of how many times it was imported.

Comment: If 'wavread.p'y first imported in 'surround.py' and than in 'vocoder.py' will it process sound.conf only once?

Comment: If processing `sound.conf` happens at the top level of the module then yes, that'll happen only the once.

Comment: Ok. But it is not good approach anyway. We make similar job in diffirent places. If configure file change format we will rewrite code in many points... I can propose following approach: 1. create config.py module. 2. config.py reads projects's configure file and create single configure structure (for example, dict cfg) in its globals(). 3. Other modules import config.py and have access to cfg. But in this approach config.py must know semantic of every directive in configure file. We can create configure API within project: just put directive descriptors into every module.

Comment: ...continue... Directive descriptor will have callback on directive handler function. So we'll get abstraction layer. Config.py first of all will perform import of every project module and prepare dictionary of all avaliable directive. Then config.py perform open() of configure file. Then config.py will scan configure file and if there is appropriate descriptor for current directive it will call appropriate callback. Is it good approach? Could you propose your ideas?